# Is it possible to store credentials for automatic Team Foundation Server login?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs, credentials

Is it possible to store the **credentials** that I use to connect to my **Team Foundation Server** directly in **Visual Studio 2010**?

I would like to avoid inserting them at every VS launch.

The problem is that the machine that host TFS is not in the domain and I am connecting using the credentials of a user created on that machine.

Suppose that the machine name is TOOLS and the user is Marco, I need to insert every time

```
 User name: TOOLS\Marco 
 Password: *
```

Can you suggest a possible fix for this, if it exists?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

On Windows 7 (and vista?) you can stop TFS prompting for passwords all the time by adding in a windows credential in Control Panel -> User Accounts -> User Accounts -> Manage your credentials.

Windows XP: `Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Advanced -> Manage Passwords`

Add a windows credential for your tfs server.
You might also have to add the server to your local intranet in your internet settings.

Comment: Except that this just doesn't always work.  I did add these credentials in my Windows 7 credentials manager and added the server to my Local Intranet zone, and VS2005 STILL prompts me for login details when I open it.  :-(

Comment: @Jez: I was able to make it work by connecting to the TFS server by its IP address. I also configured the credential to use the IP, and added the IP to the local intranet zone.

Answer (score 18):

I found another way that works if your TFS has web access enabled.

Just use Internet Explorer to access to the TFS web site and it will prompt you with a dialog box that has the checkbox to allow you remember the credentials.

Than open Visual Studio and it should work without asking username and password.

Comment: That's what I just figured out too. My default browser is chrome, so my login for TFS never had a "remember password" feature. By opening the TFS site in IE, I got to save the password :)

Comment: note: it **has to be Internet Explorer**, chrome/firefox will not work