# Visual Studio can't remember my account information for CodePlex TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, credentials

I'm running Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, and I'm working on a project hosted on CodePlex to which I connect through TFS. Each time I open the solution, VS prompts me for the account information.

Is there any way I can make VS remember my credentials, so I don't have to enter them each time?

This is currently the only project on TFS I'm working on, but to be future-proof I'd like to save the credentials on solution-level, so I can work on other projects on other TFS servers and have those accounts saved as well.

[image: Thank you senzacionale for the screen shot]

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645085/is-it-possible-to-store-credentials-for-auotmatic-team-foundation-server-login

Comment: This is indeed a dupe. Couldn't find that question in my searches, though - I focused my search terms on remembering the password, rather than automating the login process...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the Windows 7 Credentials Manager to store your login credentials to the site.

Go to **Control Panel -> User Accounts and Family Safety -> Credentials Manager -> Add Windows Credential** and enter the address and your credentials as following:

[image]